# React to a writing error

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog, sd-card

#### Hi there,

I'm curently working on a debian system, this system (under Jessie) write datas to an SDcard really often, sometimes (i'm working on it but it is not the question here) the system is unable to write because of an error (extracted from kernel.log):

```
FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): unable to read inode block for updating (i_pos 892422)
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 57824
mmcblk0: error -110 sending status command, retrying
...
```

(If you have a good idea of why it does that...)

What i would like to do is to send me an email with the kernel.log and syslog and, if it is possible (it should), run a script when this occurs.

While the final idea is to discover what is the real source of this error, I have only one solution when this occurs: run fsck on the sdcard and restart my process.

Comment: replace sd card

Comment: I just did, but when i ran check flash (a flash memory tester under windows, it does just write datas to the card and read it, erase it and restart many times) on it, it did not find any problem in my sdcard... That is why i suppose the problem is coming from something else...

Comment: And even if it solves this problem, It could be really helpfull to be able to react when an error occurs one day...

Comment: Maybe [swatch](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7807/) will do what you want.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That is exactly what i needed! Thanks!